# suspend in UseCase vs Repository

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, repository-pattern, coroutine, suspend

I have a stupid question..... but I cannot find the information.

I have created a `Repository.kt` , which using Co-Routine

The code is as below:

```
        override suspend fun getChallenge(): AwsResult<String> {
                return awsApi.getChallenge()
        }
```

The AwsAPI part is done as below:

```
override suspend fun getChallenge(): AwsResult<String> {
       ....

        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val reponse: ... => API call through SDK
                AwsResult.onSuccess(reponse.text)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                AwsResult.onError(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have created a `ChallengeUseCase.kt` which will contain a little buit of logic before sending back the result to the ViewModel.

```
     suspend fun registerDevice(): Result<String> {
        try {
            val result = repository.getChallenge()
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
    }
```

and the `AwsResult` looks like:

```
sealed class AwsResult<out R> {
    data class onSuccess<out T>(val data: T) : AwsResult<T>()
    data class onError(val exception: Exception) : AwsResult<Nothing>()
}
```

I would like to know how do I catch the `AwsResult` in the use case file ? the goal is to extract an information, do something with it and the sending back to the viewModel the result of the business logic implemented. I assume that `result` will not contain right away the information and that I have to probably defined a scope or something around that.

When I say, that I assume that the result will not contain right away the info, it's because I try to catch the `onSuccess` and `onResult` in the `UseCase.kt`.

Any idea ?

Comment: "I assume that result will not contain right away the information" - why you assume that? Have you tested? You always can test before ask such questions. `result` will contain the `AwsResult` instance after calling `repository.getChallenge()`.

Comment: @BigSt I have added the answer in the description

Comment: `getChallenge` and `registerDevice` are `suspend` functions, when you call `getChallenge` the `registerDevice` function waits while the execution of it finishes and the resulting `AwsResult` object is returned.

Comment: But how can I extract on Success or onError ? @BigSt

Comment: What is this object `AwsResult`? Can you show the source code of it or a link to the docs?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract `onSuccess` or `onError` using `when` operator and checking a type of the returned `result`:

```
suspend fun registerDevice(): Result<String> {
    try {
        val result: AwsResult<String> = repository.getChallenge()
        when (result) {
            is AwsResult.onSuccess -> {
                val data = result.data
                // ... do something when request is success
            }
            is AwsResult.onError -> {
                val exception = result.exception
                // ... do something when request is error
            }
        }
        
    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
}
```

Also I wouldn't recommend to name Kotlin classes starting with a small letter, the good style is to name classes starting with a big letter:

```
sealed class AwsResult<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : AwsResult<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : AwsResult<Nothing>()
}
```